# Native code Windows8 Development without VS?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, c99, native-code

Since the VS C compiler has never done C99 very well I have always done my native code C development for desktop using a (terrible) port of gcc to windows. Anyway, I was wondering will WINRT's "native code" platform allow code from other compilers or will we need to use VS?

And when I say WINRT I mean the APIs not the OS... or at least I think I do... whatever metro apps want to call themselves now...

I just want to know if switching to metro development will be a good idea any time in the near future?

Comment: Metro apps wants to call themselves "Windows Store Apps" now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need VS. But you do need a native compiler.